# Example of data race in a multithreaded program fails inside VMs (Virtualbox, VMware)

Tags: pthreads, virtual-machine, virtualization, race-condition

I am trying to run some thread test examples on both Debian (virtualbox, gcc 4) and Ubuntu (VMware, gcc 7.0.2) as an introduction to C++11 thread learning. Virtualization is turned on on both virtual machines. Host is Windows 10.

Link to example (under Race Conditions):
https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2013/spring/12300-1/labs/lab6/

Output of a program is always constant, but should differ (look at bash scripts and outputs). What can be a reason for this constant output?

Everything works fine on arch Linux (Virtualbox, gcc 7.3).

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow! Take some time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how it functions and what is the best way to get help here. In particular, please copy the program's  code into the question's body. It is not guaranteed that the original website will not change or become unavailable tomorrow. Besides, there are many snippets there — which one are your concerns about?

Comment: How many times did you run the program? Have you tried running it ten times more? A hundred times more?

Comment: Thanks for a tip. First time I have run it with a script about 5*100 times and there was no difference. Then I changed VMware settings - number of cores from 1 to 2. I know that should not have changed anything, but it did and now I can observe a variety of results and also I run it even more times per one test (1000), so I guess my tests were faulty.

Comment: It cannot be a data race if there is nobody to race! You literally need two or more threads running concurrently.

Comment: Of course, there were 20 threads there.